# My code changing by adding newlnes when i save it

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, settings, newline

when i save my code in vs code new lines between my codes ' <> specially ' appears,please help me

My code after the change:
[image: My code after the change]

Comment: please send the code here. not in image mode. thanks. @abdennour

Comment: thanks bro it answer my question exactly